# What is the expected return type for tokenizer that is passed as parameter into Tfidfvectorizer

Tags: scikit-learn, vectorization, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I am looking at:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html

It just says:

> tokenizer : callable or None (default) Override the string
>   tokenization step while preserving the preprocessing and n-grams
>   generation steps. Only applies if analyzer == 'word'.

What should the function return ? A list of words ? Is there an example somewhere showing the data structure that must be returned by this function ?

EDIT: For example, if I am writing my own custom tokenizer function, what should it return.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py#L236

Comment: More specifically, it should be a collection (a list preferably) of words.